# Custom authenticator with password expiry handling in Spring

Tags: spring-security, change-password, custom-authentication

We have an existing application that uses Spring security. We need to have password expiry option for the users. We already have a column that has the *passwordExpirationDate*. What would be way to have my *AuthenticationProvider/Manger* to redirect to password reset page after the *passwordExpirationDate*